# Adding records to has_and_belongs_to_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I want to implement many to many relation between these two models:

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :betting_event
  has_and_belongs_to_many :gambler_bets
  validates_presence_of :odd, :outcome, :description, :betting_event_id 

end
```

And

```
class GamblerBet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gambler
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bets

end
```

I wrote and ran a migration :

```
class CreateBetsGamblerBets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bets_gambler_bets, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :bet
      t.belongs_to :gambler_bet
    end
  end
end
```

So the question is: **where** and **how** to write a method that would add bets to a `Gambler` and store every one of them with `bet_id` and `gambler_bet_id` in `bets_gambler_bet` table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement HABTM, I think you need many to many between Gambler and Bet. You would require the following in Bet model:

```
#bet.rb
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :gamblers
end
```

and the following in Gambler model:

```
#gambler.rb
class Gambler < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :bets
end
```

and this would be your migration with table name `bets_gamblers`

```
class CreateBetsGamblers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bets_gamblers, :id => false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :bets
        t.belongs_to :gamblers
    end
  end
end
```

To query bets of a Gambler with instance of `@gambler`

```
@gambler.bets #this would give you all the bets of a gambler
```

To insert a bet `@bet` into the bets of a `@gambler`

```
@gambler.bets << @bet
```

You can do a similar thing with your model `GamblerBet`, but if its only for having a many to many relation between Gambler and Bet, the relation above would work better.

Comment: you answered my question, but I will stick with my relation because Gambler can have multiple gambler bets that consist of multiple different Bets. `@gambler_bet.bets << @bet` can I surround this code in method in `GamblerBet` model? @Raman

Comment: Yes for sure a method like the following can be added to `GamblerBet`:

    def add_bet(bet)
        self.bets << bet
    end